# Prove that $(\mathbb {P},.)$ is not a cyclic group, where $\mathbb {P}=\mathbb {Q}^+,\mathbb {Q}^*,\mathbb {R}^+,\mathbb {R}^*,\mathbb {C}^*$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Prove that $(\mathbb {P},.)$  is not a cyclic  group, where $\mathbb {P}=\mathbb {Q}^+,\mathbb {Q}^*,\mathbb {R}^+,\mathbb {R}^*,\mathbb {C}^*$

My solution goes like this:

> Clearly, $(\mathbb {Q}^+,.)$ is a group. If $(\mathbb {Q}^+,.)$ was a cyclic group then $\exists\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb {Q}^+$ such that $gcd(p,q)=1$ and $q>0$. So, $\exists n\in\mathbb {Z}$ such that $(\frac{p}{q})^n =q$ since, $q\in\mathbb {Q}^+$. So, we get, $p^n=q^{n+1}$ , which means $p|q$ , a contradiction.  Hence, $(\mathbb {Q}^+,.)$ is not a cyclic group. Also, we know that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.  Now, $(\mathbb{C}^*,.)$ is also not a cyclic group as $\mathbb {Q}^+\subset \mathbb{C}^*$ . Also, $(\mathbb{R}^*,.),(\mathbb{R}^+,.)$ is not a cyclic group as  $\mathbb {Q}^+\subset \mathbb{R}^+$ and  $\mathbb {Q}^+\subset \mathbb{R}^*$.Similarly, $(\mathbb {Q}^*,.)$ is not a cyclic group.

Is the above solution correct? Is it valid? If not,  where is it going wrong?

Comment: The second sentence is incomplete, as you don't say that $p/q$ generates $\mathbb Q^+$. Also, you are a little bit quick to conclude a contradiction. You need to consider the case $p=1$ first.

Comment: Your reasoning for $\mathbb R^+$ is incorrect, since non-cyclic subgroups may contain cyclic subgroups. But of course, $\mathbb R^\ast$ and $\mathbb R^+$ are not cyclic since they contains $\mathbb Q^+$.

Comment: Besides that, the global reasoning is good, especially noticing that it is sufficient to show that the smallest group (for inclusion) is not cyclic

Comment: How you obtain $p|q$ is not clear to me. Shouldn't it be $q|p$ because we need "more" of $q$ to be equal to $p$?